# Style HTML element based on its title using CSS

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to apply a style to an HTML element using only its title as a unique identifier?  For example:

```
<div class="my_class">
    <a href="some site" title="MyTitle">My Link</a>
</div>
```

I would like to write a rule that will apply only to link element within a div of class my_class and the link title MyTitle.

I do not have the ability to change page layout, however, I can use a custom CSS file that is included automatically.

Thank you

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It sure is, using what's called *attribute selectors*; these are part of CSS2. In your particular case, you'd use:

```
div.my_class a[title="MyTitle"] { color: red; }
```

You can read more about attribute selectors here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors

Comment: It should be noted that IE6 does not support attribute selectors

Comment: Alas, IE6 doesn't support a lot of stuff. Onwards and upwards, though! ;)

Comment: You could hack through IE6 non support using javascript. ie in jQuery: $('div.my_class a[title="MyTitle"]').css('color', 'red'); And then put it away using conditional comments and everyone will be happy.

Comment: you could do this with expressions in IE6 but that would be a pretty ugly hack

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors

You would say A[title="MyTitle] I believe.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is css attribute selectors:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors

a[title]
   {
      ...
   }

Answer (score 3):

CSS specifications identify a number of "selectors" that may help you here.  For example, you could apply a rule such as the following:

```
.my_class a[title="MyTitle"]
{
   ...
}
```

You can see a detailed specification of CSS "selectors" here:

http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/

Answer (score 1):

Although it is possible, using attribute selectors (see http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors ) Internet Explorer 6 does not support it (see http://kimblim.dk/css-tests/selectors/ )

An example from the W3C site: H1[title] { color: blue; }